# How to disable EhCache for JUnit Test Cases

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, ehcache

I am trying to write a test case for my service which uses EhCache for caching , but the problem is for Test cases I don't need it to be cached.So I can I disable it for test cases.
I am working with Gradle project Set up.

Comment: you can use spring profiles

Comment: I am using it. I don't understand how to pass "-Dnet.sf.ehcache.disabled=true" in profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `@SpringBootTest`, then you can add `@TestPropertySource(properties={"net.sf.ehcache.disabled=true"})` to your test class.

Comment: test {
       systemProperty "net.sf.ehcache.disabled", true
    }...Set it in build.gradle in your Root project and you are ready to rock..Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We need to restrict from adding elements in cache.

This is done by setting the net.sf.ehcache.disabled system property

You can set this property by `-Dnet.sf.ehcache.disabled=true` from command 
line

You can also give this property in right click project: `Run Configuration -> Arguments tab -> add in VM Arguments box`

Comment: I had set it in Run Configuration as well as command Line[while adding it to command Line it would work for only starting the server , it would not work for JUnit test cases.] and it was working fine.Thanks for responding